# Prelim problem in real analysis (any hints)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Find all constants $K > 0$ for which the following holds:

If $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$  is any positive measure space and if $f:X\to \mathbb{R} $ is $\mu$ integrable satisfying $\left|\int_E f\,d\mu\right|<K$ for all $E\in \Sigma$, then $\|f\|_1<1$.

Any hints to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider $E = \{x: f(x) \ge 0\}$ and $\{x: f(x) \le 0\}$ .

Comment: So is the answer just $(0,1]$?

Comment: No.  If $a < 1$ and $b < 1$, is $a + b < 1$?

Comment: You sir, are wonderful. :)